# Unrecognized VM option 'G1ReclaimDeadHumongousObjectsAtYoungGC'

Tags: java

```
java version "1.8.0_191"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.191-b12, mixed mode)
```

The above flag seems to be unrecognized. What happened to it? I was trying to solve my problems around humongous objects

Comment: It's fully possible that the root problem also disappeared with changes to the GC. Run your project without that flag and see if you still have huge object issues.

Comment: yes my gc logs are usually having a good amount of `G1 Humongous allocation` logs which occupies roughly 600 regions. Do I have to be worried of it? My JVM heap pattern is no longer a sawtooth

Comment: I don't know whether you have to be worried about it, because that question is based on the effect the objects are or aren't having on your user.  Is your application server running out of memory? Are you experiencing pauses that cause unacceptable delays for the user?

Comment: yes we've been facing some issues lately around elasticsearch. it has a circuit breaker capability that queries the JVM about heap usage. We are seeing false reporting from the JVM / Indeed the JVM is spiked up at that moment and we need to figure out why reclamation isn't happening @nanofarad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JDK-8048179](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8048179) renamed this flag to `G1EagerReclaimHumongousObjects` and also renamed the flag that tries to do this in spite of stale refs: `G1EagerReclaimHumongousObjectsWithStaleRefs`.

Additionally, using a much newer JVM may lead to significant benefits since major GC improvements have occurred since Java 8.

Comment: thanks! we use jdk12 but we've been witnessing almost 1000 regions occupied by humongous objects. unsure why aren't they collected sooner / when do they collected with/without the above flag

Comment: @Faiz no problem. It's not 100% clear if this is a bug of the JDK vs a poorly designed elastic search circuit breaker. Perhaps disabling it or tuning it might allow elastic search to run without encountering troubles, if it's tuned to be overly sensitive to a JVM memory metric that isn't an issue on its own.

Comment: yes. our application indeed is generating large JSON documents that will make the JVM mark them as humongous. that's the first thing we're fixing to see if it helps. we'll adjust the JVM parameters as a last resort

Comment: @FaizHalde they are not collected sooner because : a) they are still reacheable or b) there was no need for collecting them according to the heuristics. P.S. you should accept this answer and ask a diff question, IMO.